# Angular Split() And innerHTML

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I wanna print my array with innerHTML, but I can't print my defined variable, because the system could not find my defined variable I tried the global variable but It didn't work

Not: Text1 is an array

dashboard.component.ts:

```
  p :any;
  bol = Text1.forEach(function(element){
  let deger = element.text.split(' ');
  let p = `${deger}`;
  return p ;
  })
```

dashboard.component.html:

```
  <p class="words" [innerHTML] = 'p'>
       
  </p>
```

Comment: [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) doesn't return anything, your `bol` will always be `undefined`.

Comment: @sp00m Do you have any solution suggestions for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` can be used instead of `forEach` to create a new result:

```js
p = Text1.map(function(element){
  let deger = element.text.split(' ');
  return `${deger}`;
}).join('');
```

Map Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map